# Can I reach Mrs Macquarie's Chair without walking through the Royal Botanical Garden?

Tags: australia, walking, sydney

I'm planning to watch sunset at Mrs Macquarie's Chair with my wife and then walk to the Sydney Cove Oyster bar afterward. The [Google map route](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/Mrs+Macquarie's+Chair,+Mrs+Macquaries+Road,+Sydney,+New+South+Wales/Sydney+Cove+Oyster+Bar,+1+Circular+Quay+E,+Sydney+NSW+2000/@-33.8615304,151.213255,16z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x6b12ae7acdffd643:0x43bfb6b9da05a763!2m2!1d151.2225852!2d-33.8596897!1m5!1m1!1s0x6b12ae67d5fed25b:0xb04f44727223d32e!2m2!1d151.2127505!2d-33.8594016!3e2) suggests that the walk cuts through the Royal Botanical Garden, which I understand closes at 5 pm.

Would I be able to walk from Mrs Macquarie's Chair to the Sydney Cove Oyster after sunset, or because the Garden closed we have to take a longer detour? How long will the detour be?

Comment: I believe it's the building that closes, not the footpaths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a lovely plan!  Michael Hampton is partialy correct, in that the 5pm time refers to the café/buildings in the park and not the footpaths. However, the gates to the Gardens close around dusk each night. If you'll be going before March, you will have until 8pm to enjoy the Gardens. For a full schedule, see the hours shown [HERE.](https://www.rbgsyd.nsw.gov.au/Visit/Opening-Times)

Additionally, I would recommend that rather than walk through the Gardens after the chair, you take the wonderfully scenic walk along the waterfront. It will take you right past the Opera House and provide lovely views of the harbour, the gardens, and the bridge. Google's route may be slightly quicker (no more than a few minutes), but it is much less scenic. If you want to walk through the gardens, I recommend doing so during daylight. It was always one of my favorite places to spend an afternoon in Sydney.  Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for the info! We'll be there next week. If we take the waterfront path as you recommend, then the Garden hours no longer matters, correct? Also, [Google says sunset is 8 pm](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=sydney+sunset+time&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Does that mean we should be at the chair at 8 pm? I'm booking a table at the moment and trying to find the best time.

Comment: Allow at least half an hour between the time of sunset and the start of dinner, as the time of sunset published is not always taken on the beach but a bit more inland, and you will want to linger a bit after the actual sunset to see the colours of the sky fade.